# Cisco Guestshell - Bridging of VirtualPortGroup0

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios

i'm fiddling around with ne virtual-services functions of IOS-XE.

Is there a possibility to bring interface "VirtualPortGroup0" into a bridge domain with some physical interface of the router?

It's neither possible to configure a bridge-group nor a layer2 Service Instance with bridge-domains on this interface.

My aim is to put Guestshell (or any other virtual service) into an existing VLAN with other hosts in the same broadcast domain.

Mm current workaround is to configure a 1:1 NAT between the Guestshell and the external VLAN which works fine, but not as straightforward as i would like.

Comment: It depends on what network device you are using. What model and software version are you running?

Comment: Currently i'm testing a ISR1111-8P with IOS 16.12.01a